# runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'ListNode'

Tags: c++, linked-list, runtime-error, nodes

I have spent a lot of time on it but still getting the same error. Please someone help.
I have written this code for a leetcode question.(merging two linked lists)
have read many similar answers but still cannot figure out

```
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* mergeTwoLists(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2)
    {
        ListNode* third = NULL;
        ListNode* last = NULL;
        if (l1 && l2) {
            if (l1->val < l2->val) {
                third = last = l1;
                l1 = l1->next;
                last->next = NULL;
            }
            else {
                third = last = l2;
                l2 = l2->next;
                last->next = NULL;
            }
        }

        while (l1 && l2) {
            if (l1->val < l2->val) {
                last->next = l1;
                last = l1;
                l1 = l1->next;
                last->next = NULL;
            }
            else {
                last->next = l2;
                last = l2;
                l2 = l2->next;
                last->next = NULL;
            }
        }

        if (l1) {
            last->next = l1;
        }

        if (l2) {
            last->next = l2;
        }

        return third;
    }
};
```

Comment: For example suppose l1 and l2 equaled NULL. Can you see why your function would crash in that case? Actually you'd get the same crash if either l1 or l2 was equal to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You only set `last` to a non-null value if both inputs are non-null.

You need to check it first, for instance with

```
if (last)
{
    last->next = l1 ? l1 : l2;
}
```